# Passing data from one fragment to another fragment from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am new to this. I know there are a lot of questions about this but I can't solve this problem. I want to pass data from one fragment to another fragment through firebaserecycleradapter

This is my first Fragment

```
private  FirebaseDatabase database;
private  DatabaseReference mReference;
private  RecyclerView recyclerView_food;
private  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private  LinearLayout nonVegBtn;
private  HomeItem adapterHome;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_home, container, false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        recyclerView_food=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.homeFoodRecycleView);
        recyclerView_food.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        Query query = mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categoria");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Categoria> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Categoria>().
                setQuery(query,Categoria.class).build();
        adapterHome = new HomeItem(options);
        recyclerView_food.setAdapter(adapterHome);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapterHome.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapterHome.stopListening();
    }
}
```

This is the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter from which I want to pass the data to the second fragment, I used the Bundle method but it doesn't work

```
public class HomeItem extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Categoria,HomeItem.viewHolder>{

    public HomeItem(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Categoria> options) {
        super(options);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Categoria model) {

        String getID=getRef(position).getKey();


        holder.texFood.setText(model.getName());
        Glide.with(holder.imageFood.getContext()).load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.non_veg).into(holder.imageFood);
        holder.itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("categoryID",getID);
                AllFoodItem newsFragment = new AllFoodItem();
                newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

               AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity =(AppCompatActivity)holder.itemButton.getContext();
               appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameItemLeyaut,
                       new AllFoodItem()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_item,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(v);
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView texFood;
        public ImageView imageFood;
        public LinearLayout itemButton;

        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            texFood=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nonVegtxt);
            imageFood=itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodIMG);
            itemButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nonVegBtn);
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the second fragment where I want to get the data. Please help me what method to use

```
public class AllFoodItem extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference mReference;
    private FoodViewHolder adapterFood;
    String getIdFood ="";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_food_item, container, false);

        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("food");

        mRecyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.nonVegRecyclerView);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle!=null){
            getIdFood=bundle.getString("categoryID");
        }

        Query query = mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("food");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>().
                setQuery(query.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(getIdFood),Food.class).build();
        adapterFood = new FoodViewHolder(options);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterFood);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapterFood.stopListening();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapterFood.startListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your new fragment, you create an instance of it (`newsFragment`) and set its arguments here

```java
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("categoryID",getID);
AllFoodItem newsFragment = new AllFoodItem();
newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

then when you go on to start the fragment you *completely ignore* the fragment instance you just created, and create a new instance here (with no bundle arguments set)

```java
appCompatActivity.
    getSupportFragmentManager().
    beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.frameItemLeyaut, new AllFoodItem()). // <- here
    addToBackStack(null).
    commit();
```

Instead of calling `new AllFoodItem()` there you should pass in the fragment instance you already created and set the arguments on, like this

```java
appCompatActivity.
    getSupportFragmentManager().
    beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.frameItemLeyaut, newsFragment). // <- here
    addToBackStack(null).
    commit();
```